# YouTube API for Monetization

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

This is my Java Code to YouTube API for Live Streaming

```
        LiveBroadcastSnippet broadcastSnippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
        broadcastSnippet.setTitle(name);
        broadcastSnippet.setDescription(description);
        broadcastSnippet.setScheduledStartTime(new DateTime(futureDate));
        broadcastSnippet.set("categoryId",17);

        LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = new LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
        MonitorStreamInfo monitorStream = new MonitorStreamInfo();
        monitorStream.setEnableMonitorStream(true);
        contentDetails.setMonitorStream(monitorStream);
        contentDetails.setEnableAutoStart(true);
        contentDetails.setEnableAutoStop(false);
        contentDetails.setEnableEmbed(true);
        contentDetails.setEnableClosedCaptions(true);
        // Create LiveBroadcastStatus with privacy status.
        LiveBroadcastStatus status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
        //status.setPrivacyStatus("unlisted");

        LiveBroadcast broadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
        broadcast.setKind("youtube#liveBroadcast");
        broadcast.setSnippet(broadcastSnippet);
        broadcast.setStatus(status);
        broadcast.setContentDetails(contentDetails);

        LiveBroadcastMonetizationDetails monetizationDetails = new LiveBroadcastMonetizationDetails();
        CuepointSchedule cuepointSchedule = new CuepointSchedule();
        cuepointSchedule.setEnabled(true);
        monetizationDetails.setCuepointSchedule(cuepointSchedule);
        broadcast.setMonetizationDetails(monetizationDetails);

        // Create the insert request
        String[] lbInsert = {"snippet", "status","contentDetails", "monetizationDetails"};

        YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Insert liveBroadcastInsert = youtube
                .liveBroadcasts().insert(Arrays.asList(lbInsert),
                        broadcast);
        // Request is executed and inserted broadcast is returned
        LiveBroadcast returnedBroadcast = liveBroadcastInsert.execute();
```

This code is working fine. But the issue I am facing is, it is not enabling Monetization On (true), it is always False, I have to enable it manually.

I guess this code that enables monetization for live streaming video.

```
    LiveBroadcastMonetizationDetails monetizationDetails = new LiveBroadcastMonetizationDetails();
    CuepointSchedule cuepointSchedule = new CuepointSchedule();
    cuepointSchedule.setEnabled(true);
    monetizationDetails.setCuepointSchedule(cuepointSchedule);
    broadcast.setMonetizationDetails(monetizationDetails);

    // Create the insert request
    String[] lbInsert = {"snippet", "status","contentDetails", "monetizationDetails"};

    YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Insert liveBroadcastInsert = youtube
            .liveBroadcasts().insert(Arrays.asList(lbInsert),
                    broadcast);
```

This is the return value I am getting

```
{"contentDetails":{"closedCaptionsType":"closedCaptionsHttpPost","enableAutoStart":true,"enableAutoStop":false,"enableClosedCaptions":true,"enableContentEncryption":false,"enableDvr":true,"enableEmbed":true,"enableLowLatency":false,"latencyPreference":"normal","monitorStream":{"broadcastStreamDelayMs":0,"embedHtml":"<iframe width=\"425\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/tttt?autoplay=1&livemonitor=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share\" allowfullscreen></iframe>","enableMonitorStream":true},"projection":"rectangular","recordFromStart":true,"startWithSlate":false},"etag":"WJp38q19VZEauJyCUyTVdDiVUc8","id":"tttt","kind":"youtube#liveBroadcast","monetizationDetails":{}
```

Like to know whether I am doing any mistake ?

Comment: I think thats working as intended

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Monetization is still enabled status is showing as OFF

Unable to make it as ON